# Angular NG-Repeat Complete

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a page using ng-repeat & templates.
Each iteration of ng-repeat creates a checkbox.
I want to be able to convert each of these checkboxes into a flipswitch (using a third party library I have included) but I don't know how to accurately know how/when Angular has finished creating the page.
I've tried using ng-init and $last but can't get a solution around that method working.
Is there a way of knowing when angular has finished so I can run the flipswitch init code?

Thanks

Comment: Use $timeout within directive which is placed in the ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism built into angular to know when it is done processing the page. Instead of trying to convert all of the checkboxes after your page has finished loaded, which is a JQuery paradigm and will hinder your growth as an Angular developer, look directive.

Basically you would have an element such as:

```
<input type="checkbox" my-flip-switch>
```

Within the my-flip-switch directive you would convert that specific element to a flip switch as it is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

as I understand you want to detect when the ng-repeat finished so you initialize the flipswitch ,,

ok add this directive to your module

```
.directive('repeatDone', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) { // all are rendered
            scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
        }
    }
})
```

now whenever you have an ng-repeat you can use it like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" repeat-done="initFlip()">
```

NOTE : initFlip should be defined inside the same scope of items

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both answers work for me but I ended up going with Enzey's.